# How to create folder on server pc in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How can I create folder on the server-pc on a button click

```
protected void BtnCreateFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\NewFolder1");
}
```

This code create folder on my local-pc, how can i create folder on server-pc with server-pc ip

Comment: give server address. like `//servername/path-that-is-shared-to-you/`. It should work fine.

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));` this might create it

Comment: You can assuming a) you have rights to b) you have a path to add it to.. or c) you run an app on the server end that can do it

Comment: @Mohit `Server.MapPath()` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @CodeCaster right, sorry. but i bet Usf Noor will stumble upon it (permission problem) and at least it already had the code for creating a directory on remote drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [MSDN: Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can create a directory on a remote computer, on a share that you have write access to. UNC paths are supported;

Keyword here being "UNC paths", which take the following form:

```
\\server-name\share-name\[subdirectory-names\]
```

So:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\server-name\share-name\NewFolder1");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string directoryPath = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/{0}/", "NewFolder1"));
 if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
          Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
```

this will create your newfolder1 and also check whether there is an another folder with same name.

Comment: think that you should use ```Path.Combine``` to combining paths :) But, anyway, OP was asked about creating folder on remote machine.